# Install starspan configure error

Tags: python, cmd, configure

I want to install [starspan](https://github.com/Ecotrust/starspan). I downloaded and extracted the file. In the command line I navigated to the starspan folder and typed `configure` according to the [install file](https://github.com/Ecotrust/starspan/blob/master/INSTALL). However I am only getting back:

```
'configure' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am on Windows 7 (64it).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this software at all, but the commands in that file --  `./configure` etc. -- are part of the GNU Autotools system, which are typically used to compile software from source in a *nix environment. Are you expecting to compile this on your machine? If not, you'll probably want to look for Windows binaries instead.

A little follow-up: It looks like this project relies on MinGW (http://www.mingw.org/) in Windows. That's another piece of software I'm not familiar with, but it looks like it comes with GCC (a compiler), a shell, and some other components. It could be you just need to install that first, drop into the shell it provides, and run those commands from there.